# Inserting a row to a View

Tags: sql, oracle

I wonder if someone can help me with adding a row into a view in Oracle

I have a view and what I want to do is add a blank row with id and name if that particular ID is missing an event from a list of event which is in field called event.

The columns in the view are id, name, date, event, status. Each person should complete number of events from the list but if they are missing an event I want to insert a row with all the details with a text saying missing event in the event column for that particular id.

I haven't done this before and don't know where to make a start. Can someone guide on this please?.

select id,name,date,event,status
from status

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text (not images...)

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for your table(s) (as **text** that can be copy/pasted and not as images); the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; **YOUR** attempt at creating a view; the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt; the expected output.

Comment: "I want to be able to add a row just like highlighted in the sample data if id 67 is missing Day3 Event in a view without touching the original table." If you have no information about Day 3 in your table then how do you know to include that row? A database can only work with the information that it has so you either need to give it the information about all the events (usually in a separate table) or you need to generate a table-like result set and hardcode it into the query underlying the view.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood it, it is an outer join along with `NVL` (or `coalesce`; pick one you prefer).

Here's an example based on Scott's schema (as I don't have your tables):

There are departments 30 and 40:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM dept
  3   WHERE deptno IN (30, 40);

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Nobody works in department 40:

```
SQL> SELECT deptno, empno, ename
  2    FROM emp
  3   WHERE deptno IN (30, 40);

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME
---------- ---------- ----------
        30       7499 ALLEN
        30       7521 WARD
        30       7654 MARTIN
        30       7698 BLAKE
        30       7844 TURNER
        30       7900 JAMES

6 rows selected.
```

View, as join of these two tables, should be *outer join* (otherwise you wouldn't get department 40). `NVL` is used to "populate" missing column value:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_emp
  2  AS
  3     SELECT d.deptno,
  4            d.dname,
  5            e.empno,
  6            NVL (e.ename, 'Missing person') ename
  7       FROM dept d LEFT JOIN emp e ON e.deptno = d.deptno
  8      WHERE d.deptno IN (30, 40);

View created.
```

Result:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM v_emp
  3  ORDER BY deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME               EMPNO ENAME
---------- -------------- ---------- --------------
        30 SALES                7499 ALLEN
        30 SALES                7521 WARD
        30 SALES                7654 MARTIN
        30 SALES                7698 BLAKE
        30 SALES                7844 TURNER
        30 SALES                7900 JAMES
        40 OPERATIONS                Missing person       --> this

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now, try to apply that to your case.

Comment: I'd recommend COALESCE instead of NVL, since it's standard SQL and very portable.

Comment: thank you so much for the response. This wouldn't work for my case as all the information is coming from one table in the view.

Comment: I have added a picture of sample data. I want to show the highlighted row if id 67 is missing event Day3 Event.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE events (
  id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(20) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE activities (
  id       NUMBER,
  name     VARCHAR2(20),
  "DATE"   DATE,
  team     VARCHAR2(20),
  event_id REFERENCES events (id),
  status   VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Then you can create the view using a partitioned outer join:

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_name (id, name, "DATE", team, event, status) AS
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a."DATE",
       a.team,
       e.name,
       a.status
FROM   events e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN activities a
       PARTITION BY (a.id, a.name)
       ON (e.id = a.event_id)
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO events (id, name)
SELECT 1, 'Shotput'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Javelin'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Discus'    FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO activities (id, name, "DATE", team, event_id, status)
SELECT 1, 'Alice', DATE '1970-01-01', 'A-Team', 1, 'accepted' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Alice', DATE '1970-01-02', 'A-Team', 2, 'accepted' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Alice', DATE '1970-01-03', 'A-Team', 3, 'declined' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty', DATE '1970-01-01', 'A-Team', 1, 'accepted' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty', DATE '1970-01-02', 'A-Team', 3, 'declined' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the view contains:

```sql
SELECT * FROM view_name;
```

> | ID | NAME | DATE | TEAM | EVENT | STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Alice | 01-JAN-70 | A-Team | Shotput | accepted |
> | 1 | Alice | 02-JAN-70 | A-Team | Javelin | accepted |
> | 1 | Alice | 03-JAN-70 | A-Team | Discus | declined |
> | 2 | Betty | 01-JAN-70 | A-Team | Shotput | accepted |
> | 2 | Betty | *null* | *null* | Javelin | *null* |
> | 2 | Betty | 02-JAN-70 | A-Team | Discus | declined |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f51a86e51ec95a24fd58788c2518ecd0)*

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, the only constraint with my data is all the information is  in one table including the events and there isnt any event id in the table. I have added a picture of sample data in my question above if that's any helpful to understand the situation.